# How can I deserialize JSON i Silverlight?

Tags: json, silverlight, serialization

I've created a service for my silverlight application, and in the service I have the function that returns a string, `GetAllUsers()`. It creates a List and returns `JsonConvert.Serialize(list)`.

So in the silverlight i asyncly get the result string, but silverlight wont add JSON from newtonsoft so how could I deserialize it?

Comment: newtonsoft json.net supports silverlight. Use proper version/build or NUGET

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what technologies you use, so I assume that this is a general question about how to parse JSON data in Silverlight. I have written a [tutorial in my blog](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/working-with-json-web-services-in-silverlight-and-windows-phone-7/), it is for Windows Phone but will work in Silverlight too. Or you can use the example from [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

A general algorithm would be like this:

1. Create model classes with DataContract and DataMember attributes.
2. Use [the default serializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) so: `new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(YourModel))`
3. Parse the stream to your model class `(YourModel)dcs.ReadObject(stream)`

If you have a string instead of a stream, you should convert it to an instance of `MemoryStream`, it is explained in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Also you can use other silverlight libraries like JSON.Net for deserializing, but I haven't worked with them so I use the default serializer.

Answer (score 0):

http://json.codeplex.com/

This is an an awesome JSON serialization package.  So good in fact, that the ASP.NET devs distribute it as a component of ASP.NET MVC.